# Does anyone know what the fingerings are for Bluebird by Alexis Ffrench?

Tags: piano, fingering

I am just learning to play this song, and it would help if I had a general idea of what the fingerings were for the song.

It would also be helpful if you could send a video on if there are some techniques to find out the fingerings of any song.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Nate. Welcome to Music Practice and Theory. Your question is too broad for what we do here, but if you are having trouble with a specific part of the song, you could post an excerpt from the score, and will almost certainly get specific answers.

Comment: The fingerings for *any* song are not 'etched in stone'. There may be *suggested* fingerings for certain songs, but generally, pianists will work out, sometimes painstakingly, what fingerings suit them best personally. I'm still doing that after 60 odd yrs of playing!

Comment: Thank you tim! But Aaron, i did a more specific question and this site deemed it as too specific. lol